# How this popup search JavaScript to add codes that close the popup window automaticly?

Tags: javascript, scroll, popup, click

*How this popup window will close automaticly after clicking on the icon and when scrolling and after 6 seconds?*

```
/* Listener */
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
    if (e.target == icon || (e.target.parentNode && e.target.parentNode == icon)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    var text = window.getSelection().toString().trim();
    if (text && icon.style.display == 'none') {
        icon.style.top = e.pageY +40 + 'px';
        if(e.pageX -70<10)
            icon.style.left='10px';
        else
            icon.style.left = e.pageX -70 + 'px';
        icon.style.display = 'block';
    } else if (!text) {
        icon.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```
/**Event*/
function tiggerEvent(el, type) {
    if ('createEvent' in document) {// modern browsers, IE9+
        var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        e.initEvent(type, false, true);// event.initEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        el.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else {// IE 8
        e = document.createEventObject();
        e.eventType = type;
        el.fireEvent('on' + e.eventType, e);
    }
}
```

```
/**Open url in new tab*/
function open(url) {
    var win;
        win = window.open(url);
    if (window.focus) {
        win.focus();
    }
    return win;
}
```

Here is the total code link: [browser popup search](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/397040-%E6%B5%8F%E8%A7%88%E5%99%A8%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2%E6%89%A9%E5%B1%95%E5%B7%A5%E5%85%B7/code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a timeout function, and it will close automatically.

```
timer = window.setTimeout(TimeOutHide, 6000);
```